# Visual Studio 2008 two projects in one solution

Tags: c++, c, header, projects

I am working in visual studio and i have got two projects in a solution.
I want to refer to header file of second project in my main-project.
I added second-prj as a reference to my main-prj,. But when i write like

```
#include "Second_Project_File.h"
```

in my main-prj it gives compile errors :

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Second_Project_File.h': No such file or directory.
```

Then i looked at the folders and gave relative path like

```
#include "..\Second_Project_Folder\Second_Project_File.h"
```

it compiled but gave error :

```
 main-prj.exe not found or not built by the last incremental link; performing full link
 Embedding manifest...
```

What should i do?

i donot want to work with this kind of including header files

```
#include "..\somefolder\header.file.h"
```

How to do this in visual studio.

Thanks.

Comment: Check the include path of first project. Does it contain second project header files' root folder? Same goes for libs

Comment: @chris but i donot see any exe files in Debug folder.

Comment: Oh i changed the debug to release in options and there it is.. my exe file.

Comment: Is there any way i donot need to give this "..\something..\filename.h" ?

Comment: Under project properties -> C++ -> General there is Additional Include Directories item. Add ../somefolder in there.

Comment: references are for managed code only, not for native C++. Also, `main-prj.exe not found or not built` is not an error it's just a message.